# Using the values of the first row of a matrix as ticks for matplotlib.pyplot.imshow

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

I have a file like this:

```
820.5   815.3   810.4
2061    2082    2098
2094    2119    2071
2067    2079    2080
2095    2080    2116
2069    2103    2108
```

and I'm using the following code to open it and plot my data

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = np.loadtxt('example.txt')
wvl = img[0,:]
data = img[1:,:]

plt.imshow(data)
```

The question is: how can I use the values inside the `numpy.ndarray` "wvl" as the x-axis tick labels for my heatmap?

I have already tried with `plt.xticks(range(wvl.size),wvl)` but in the real case the length of my array is 512 which leads to an unreadable result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the issue here is the large number of x-axis ticks. In that case, to have a readable solution, one way is to put the ticks at every `n`th step. You can additionally choose to rotate them or not as a matter of personal taste. To do so, you can do like following.

I just extended your data set four times to have mode data points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = np.loadtxt('example.txt')

wvl = img[0,:]
data = img[1:,:]
ax.imshow(data)

step = 3
plt.xticks(range(0, wvl.size, step),wvl[::step], rotation=45);
```

[image]

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I tried to reduce the range like you did but didn't tought about the `wvl[::step]` so the ticks were off; thanks a lot!